# Caption setup for package Minted

Tags: listings, captions, minted, lstlisting

When using `minted`, the spaceing below and above the code is too high. In comparsion when using a new created environment (`mintedlisting`) with the package `caption`, the spaceing seems to be right but the text won't "wrap" around the code anymore, a paragraph is inserted instead (see picture).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[newfloat=true]{minted}
    \SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{placement=h, name=Source code}
\usepackage[babel,strict=true,autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{listings}
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Source code}
\usepackage{caption}
    \newenvironment{mintedlisting}{\captionsetup{type=lstlisting}}{}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
%
\begin{listing}
\caption{Description.}
\begin{minted}{Python}
print('hello world')
\end{minted}
\end{listing}%
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{mintedlisting}
\caption{Description.}
\begin{minted}{Python}
print('hello world')
\end{minted}
\end{mintedlisting}%
%
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to use the exact spacing from `mintedlisting` environment **and** wrap the text around like `minted` does?

[image]